# Better solution or replacement of window.unload

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, onbeforeunload, stripes

Good day,

I have java web application, and I would to do something like follow after login:

1. After Login, system will display landing page, in the landing page, there will be a tab menu, and there are many module to trigger from the tab menu to navigate to different page.
2. I need implement some logic running when user trying to navigate to other page,  the logic will be a method to check something and return a `boolean`, if the `boolean` is true, then it will direct user to the page that he click from the navigation tab. If the `boolean` is false, then I want the system to direct user to a specific page.

At first, I am thinking to use the `$(window).unload()` and then do a ajax to my java code to do this logic, however, I found that the `unload` method is already remove from latest `jQuery`.

After that I found the `beforeunload` `jQuery` method. I use this and call ajax to java code. However, I found that when call ajax, it will not direct me to the specific page if my `boolean` if false, it will still direct me to the page that I click.

** My `jQquery` version is jQuery v1.12.4, and I am using `Stripes` for server code**

Any suggestion or better solution to do this approach?

Kindly advise.

Comment: This sounds both complicated and hostile. Instead, use your boolean value to toggle the `href` attributes of the links.

Comment: one approach I have seen is to use blur() on the body to trigger the warning (ie- the user moves out of the webpage to go to the navigation of the browser - they will need to leave the page / body. Not sure if it helps but it was a novel approach given the complexiities of unload / beforeunload etc)

Comment: Instead of using `href="path/to/module"`, you could use `href="#path/to/module"`, and add events to each `<a class="something">`. Then make the call to get `true/false` , take the path from `href`,  and redirect to that path (removing the #) if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, but not sure is a best practice or not.

I use the `beforeunload` jQuery as follow to call to backend code when I am leaving the landing page.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  myfun();
});
```

And then use ajax call:

```
function myfun(){
     // Write your business logic here
     var updateViewGuideUrl = '<s:url beanclass="com.cs.c.ui.customer.action.LandingAction" event="loginCheck2"/>';

            $.ajax({
                url : updateViewGuideUrl,
                success: function(data, textStatus) {
                    window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
            } 
            });
}
```